# C++ Chess Engine producing write access error

Tags: c++, chess

I am working on a basic chess engine in C++, and I want to make a move by getting a string from a user. I want to write a move like 1144, that means column 1, row 1, to column 2, row 2. I type that in, and I get an error: > ChessUltimate.exe!std::_String_valstd::_Simple_types<char>::_Large_string_engaged() Line 2282 C++
ChessUltimate.exe!std::_String_valstd::_Simple_types<char>::_Myptr() Line 2274    C++
ChessUltimate.exe!std::string::operator=(const std::string & _Right) Line 3230  C++
ChessUltimate.exe!ChessBoard::makeMove(int from_number, int from_letter, int to_number, int to_letter) Line 80  C++

> ChessUltimate.exe!main() Line 18    C++
> in the Call Stack section of Visual Studio.
> ChessEngine.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class ChessBoard
{
    public:
        string** board;
        ChessBoard(string FEN)
        {
            // Make a 2D Array
            board = new string * [8]; // Rows
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            {
                board[i] = new string[8]; // Columns
            }

            // FEN parsing logic here
            int row = 7;
            int col = 0;

            for (char c : FEN)
            {
                if (isdigit(c))
                {
                    col += c - '0';
                }
                else if (c == '/')
                {
                    row--;
                    col = 0;
                }
                else if (c != ' ')
                {
                    board[row][col] = c;
                    col++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        ~ChessBoard()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            {
                delete[] board[i];
            }
            delete[] board;
        }

        void drawChessBoard()
        {
            for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                cout << i + 1 << " ";
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
                {
                    if (board[i][j].empty())
                    {
                        if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                            cout << "|#";
                        else
                            cout << "|_";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "|" << board[i][j];
                    }
                }
                cout << "|\n";
            }
            cout << "   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n";
        }

        void makeMove(int from_number, int from_letter, int to_number, int to_letter)
        {
            board [to_number-1][to_letter-1] = board[from_number-1][from_letter - 1];
            board [from_number-1][from_letter-1] = "";
        }
};
```

ChessUltimate.cpp (main file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ChessBoard.h"

using namespace std;

ChessBoard* board;

int main()
{
    board = new ChessBoard("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR");
    board->drawChessBoard();
    while (true)
    {
        string move;
        cin >> move;
       
        board->makeMove(move[1], move[0], move[3], move[2]);
        board->drawChessBoard();
    }

    delete board;
}
```

Comment: You are using too many pointers.  You could make your life much more easier if you use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> board;`.  Right now, this two line program shows the flaws in your class: `int main() { ChessBoard b("a"); ChessBoard b2 = b; }`

Comment: `board = new ChessBoard("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR");` -- There is no need to use `new` here.  Just `ChessBoard board("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR");`.  It looks like you are using Java, C#, or python techniques in C++ code.  If you are, don't do this.  Instead, pretend none of those other languages exist.

Comment: [You don't need a single pointer in your code](https://godbolt.org/z/Yz1zj18va).

Comment: After typing in "1144" you might be surprised to learn that `move[0]` will not be 1, but 49, and `move[2]` will not be 4, but 52. VTC as a typo.

Comment: I recommend never using `new`.  But if you do have to use it, I recommend not using `new` until you have had several years of programming C++ under your belt.

Comment: You don't need to use dynamic memory or `new`.  A chess board is 8 x 8 which is 64 slots of your favorite type.  Still small enough to be a local variable.  If not convinced, you could make the board `static` and pass it by reference to other functions.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik why? What do you mean VTC as a typo? Please clarify.

Comment: It's for the same reason why you had to write `col += c - '0';` in `Chessboard::Chessboard`. This is a very common mistake. a typo, that occurs when there's confusion between characters and integers in C++. Did you try, already, to investigate this? Simply by adding `std::cout << from_number << "\n";`, or something along the same lines, ditto for the other four values, and seeing for yourself that you get 49 instead of 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SamVarshavchik, I looked up converting chars to ints, and figured it out!
My new code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ChessBoard.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ChessBoard board("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR");
    board.drawChessBoard();
    while (true)
    {
        string move;
        cin >> move;
       
        board.makeMove(move.at(1)-48, move.at(0)-48, move.at(3)-48, move.at(2)-48);
        board.drawChessBoard();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why is you board a `std::string **` to begin with? You have a board, not a pointer-to-pointer-to-strings. First `string` already holds multiple values, so `std::string []` or `char **` would be fine, but it would be better to use a different type - like `enum`. They are perfect for that as you have a small fixed number of possible chess-pieces. And it is a chess-board. It will always be 8x8.
putting that together and we have:

```
enum chessPiece {empty = 0, pawn_w, rook_w, knight_w, ..., pawn_b,....queen_b };
chessPiece board[8][8];
```

And for the user-input on the move: the ascii-characters for digits are not the same as their numeric values. `'0'` does not have the value `0` but 48. to get the corresponding integer to the users input you need to subtract that 48.
so your `board [to_number-1][to_letter-1]` would have to be `board [to_number-'0'][to_letter-'0']`.

And of course it would be a good idea to have a function that takes in the user-input, checks if it is of valid length (always 4 characters long), if the 1st and 3rd character are numeric, if the 2nd and 4th are numeric or letters, if they are all within range, and then convert them to a representation you like - like 4 ints.